# Complex SQL converted to active record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have been puzzling over the following query, and how it could be done using active record.

```
select * from links where id in 
    (select id from 
        (select votable_id as id, count(votable_id) as count from votes where vote_scope = 'flag' and votable_type = 'Link' group by votable_id ) 
     as x where count < 3);
```

I am currently using just the raw SQL query in my finder at the moment (`find_by_sql`), but was wondering if there was a more 'railsy' way of doing this?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Joachim Isaksson the query can be squashed to

```
select * from links where id in 
    (select votable_id from votes 
     where vote_scope = 'flag' 
     and votable_type = 'Link' 
     group by votable_id 
     HAVING COUNT(*) < 3) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with me not being a rails guru in any capacity, and I can't test run this so a bit "running blind". In other words, take this with a grain of salt :)

Rewriting your query as a join (assuming here your links table has `id` and one more field called `link` for the sake of the `GROUP BY`;

```
SELECT links.* 
FROM links
JOIN votes
  ON links.id = votes.votable_id
 AND votes.vote_scope = 'flag'
 AND votes.votable_type = 'Link'
GROUP BY votes.votable_id, links.id, links.link
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3;
```

[(SQLfiddle to test with)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa47e/3)

...should make something like this work (line split for readability)

```
Link.joins("JOIN votes ON links.id = votes.votable_id
            AND votes.vote_scope = 'flag' AND votes.votable_type = 'Link'")
    .group("votes.votable_id, links.id, links.link")
    .having("COUNT(*) < 3")
```

Having your associations set up correctly may allow you to [do the join in a more "railsy" way too](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables).

Comment: Thanks! This generates the following sql `SELECT "links".* FROM "links" JOIN votes ON links.id = votes.votable_id AND votes.vote_scope = 'flag' AND votes.votable_type = 'Link' GROUP BY votes.votable_id HAVING COUNT(*) < 3` which gives this error `ERROR:  column "links.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. I can't believe I didn't know about the `HAVING` SQL though. DOh. This is a great start though. I'll work on the group by issue

Comment: Also my associations are set up i.e.`Link` `has_many   :votes`

Comment: @DaveOh What are the fields in 'link'? You need to group by those too unless you're running MySQL :)

Comment: Great! Ok i got it: `Link.joins("JOIN votes ON links.id = votes.votable_id AND votes.vote_scope = 'flag' AND votes.votable_type = 'Link'")
                          .group("votes.votable_id")
                          .group("links.id")
                          .having("COUNT(*) < 3")`